# Can I use a parameter for the LIMIT condition in sqlite query

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, sql-limit

Quick question on an SQLite query I'm working on for a C# application:

**Can I use a parameter to set the "LIMIT" value in a query?** For example I would like to do this:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT @items");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("items", numberofItems));
```

Is this a thing? Or is there an equivalent? I'd like to be able to set the LIMIT value programmatically if I can.

I tried googling this question for a while, but I didn't come up with anything so maybe y'all can help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why the downvote on this question? Yes, OP could have tested it first; doesn't make the question invalid or uninteresting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this works. Don't be afraid to just test something if you are not sure if it works. You didn't mention what problems you were having. Here is a working example

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "test.db";

SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
using (connection.Open())
{
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("select * from people limit @limitNum", connection);
    command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("limitNum", 2));
    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Despertar and you're right, I should have tested it first! I realized that after I posted the question.